# How do I fix "Can't find variable: _updatePropsPaper" from react native Drawer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am not sure if there is specific code I can share. I started working on an app project I hadn't touched since last summer a couple weeks ago, and after many many errors and fixes related to getting the right/most up to date versions of everything running again it seems to MOSTLY work except that every time I use the drawer function to switch screens it gives and error that says "Can't find variable: _updatePropsPaper". The weird part is that even though it gives the error, it still goes to the proper screen, and if I dismiss the error every time I use the drawer it functions normally as far as I can tell. Is this something a newer version of react native drawer introduced that I missed while updating? Or is the problem something else? Either way, I have to figure this out as I believe this is the last existing issue before I can start actual work on the app again. If I am missing any critical information, sorry! This is my first question and also the source of this issue is (as far as I can tell) fairly ambiguous.

These are all my dependencies, in case that helps. Again, the issue seems to only occur when I switch screens with the drawer function, and it still actually changes screens, it just shows and error.

"dependencies": {
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.6",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.0",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
"expo": "^45.0.4",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.2",
"react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
"react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
"react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-web": "0.17.7",
"world-countries": "^4.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.12.9"

Comment: It seems that you are using `react-native-reanimated": "^3.0.0-rc.0"` which still in the release candidate and I don't guarantee  `@react-navigation/drawer` optimized for this new version. Can you downgrade Reanimated 2

Comment: When I downgrade to react-native-reanimated 2.8.0 it gives me "Unable to resolve ./reanimated2/fabricUtils". Is that something I can just add? or is that a different type of problem.

Comment: Try also to downgrade `@react-navigation/drawer`

Comment: What version would you suggest downgrading to?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue. For me it was a matter of various package versions being incompatible. Here are the versions that managed to fix the issue for me:

```
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "6.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure how changing versions for packages works, but can I go into the package.json file and change all of the versions there? or do I have to go through one by one installing them to try this out?

Comment: Sorry for lack of update, I did try these versions, I only had to change the gesture handler. but when I do, it now won't even compile (it did compile before) and it says "Unable to resolve module ../../TouchEventType".

Comment: @djku How did you go about changing the versions?

Comment: I used the command "npm install react-native-gesture-handler@2.2.1" as that was the only version that didn't match what you said you had.